# jQuery detect event in appended element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to detect an event in a jQuery appended element.

- How do you do this,
- and/or why isn't this working:

Here's a simplified snippet of what I've tried. The input field fires after clicking "click me." After clicking on the input, the alert isn't firing - other events on this appended input don't fire either. :-(

The following's in script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(".clickme").click(function(){$(".extra").append('write: <input type="text" class="writesomething" />');});
  $("input").click(function(){alert("clicked")});
});
```

The following's in the body:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" class="clickme">click me</a>
<div class="extra"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/eDDeZ/1/

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
    $('<input type="text" class="writesomething" />') 
             .click(function(){alert("clicked")})
             .appendTo('.extra')
             .before('write: ');
});
```

You're creating the new element, assigning the click handler directly to it, appending it to `.extra`, then adding the `write:` text before it.

No need for `.live()` this way.

---

**EDIT:**

Another option is to use `.delegate()` which will be more efficient that `.live()` since it is focused on a particular container instead of the entire page.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/eDDeZ/2/

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
    $('.extra').append('write: <input type="text" class="writesomething" />') 
});

$('.extra').delegate('input','click',function(){alert("clicked")});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @ina - You're welcome. Yes, `.delegate()` is nice. I normally like to `bind` the events directly, like in my first example, but if there are many of the same type in a container, or if you just want some convenience, `.delegate()` is great.

Answer (score 4):

The binding of the second event handler occurs when the DOM is loaded - and no matching element exists. When you click the link, an element is added but no event handler is attached to it.

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Use the `.live()` api instead of `.click()`

   ```
   $('input').live('click', function() { alert('clicked'); });
   ```
2. Add the event handler in the click event.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){   
       $(".clickme").click(function() {
           $(".extra").append('write: <input type="text" class="writesomething" />');
           $("input").click(function(){ alert("clicked") });
       });
   });
   ```
3. Or, similar, but making use of jQuery chaining

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.clickme').click(function() {
           $('<input>')
               .attr('type','text')
               .addClass('writesomething')
               .click(function() { alert('clicked!'); })
               .appendTo('.extra');
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: @To be honest, I've neaver measured performance with either of them. I would expect `live` to be the most expensive, since it has to keep track of the entire DOM tree looking for new elements, but if you look in the API documentation there's probably an easy way to limit what part of the tree you bind to, and avoid looking in more places than you need. As for the other two, I would expect them to be more or less the same, at least as long as you're not doing this a hundred thousand times.

Answer (score 1):

use the method **live** to dynamically bind events with elements instead of using **bind**.

For example :

```
$("input").live('click',function(){alert("clicked")});
```

Comment: The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the on() method instead.